# HTML, таблицы HTML, объединение ячеек

Tags: html, таблицы

Нужно сделать таблицы на HTML
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]png

```
<table border=1>
<tr height=30>
<th width=100 height=30 colspan=5></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th width=100 rowspan=3></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th width=100 height=30 ></th>
<th width=100></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
</tr>

<tr >
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
</tr>

<tr height=30>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>
<th width=100 height=30></th>

</table>
```

Comment: нужно использовать атрибуты `colspan` и `rowspan`

Comment: Я использовал, но не получилось(

Comment: Прорисовываешь все линии полностью - там, где они отсутствуют, пунктиром. И на основании этого смотришь, где использовать спаны - добавляешь соотв. спан самой левой верхней ячейке, а остальные - удаляешь вообще.

Comment: В вопросе скинул код, попробовал первый столбец объединить, но не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать свойства `rowspan` и `colspan`

пример для 2 таблицы:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
   padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

пример для 3 таблицы:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td rowspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td rowspan="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, сниппет для бОльшей информативности)

Comment: Вставил код, вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: таблица формируется правильно, единственное не указывал границы таблиц, добавил стили стили и сниппет

Comment: Всем спасибо, выручили!